# Before INSERT error when trying to update previously inserted rows

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

The structure of my table is:

```
id  id_pp id_a id_u     fecha_accion       tiempo
25    6     2   6     2018-07-06 11:53:44   NULL
26    6     3   3     2018-07-06 12:11:13   NULL
59    6     2   6     2018-07-10 10:37:28   NULL
63    6     3   3     2018-07-10 11:03:49   NULL
64    6     5   3     2018-07-10 11:03:56   NULL
65    6     7   3     2018-07-10 11:04:05   NULL
66    6     6   3     2018-07-10 11:04:08   NULL
67    6     8   3     2018-07-10 11:04:13   NULL
68    6     9   3     2018-07-10 11:04:21   NULL
```

note: fecha_accion its a timestamp.

And i want to update the previous rows with a trigger but i can't, any ideas?

TRIGGER:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS vtas_historial_acciones_BEFORE_INSERT;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `vtas_historial_acciones_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON vtas_historial_acciones 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    SET @id = (select id from vtas_historial_acciones where id_pp = new.id_pp order by id desc limit 1);
    SET @fecha = (select fecha_accion from vtas_historial_acciones where id_pp = new.id_pp order by id desc limit 1);
    
    UPDATE vtas_historial_acciones SET  `tiempo` = TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,@fecha_accion,NOW()) where id = @id;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

ERROR:

> ## 1442 - Can't update table 'vtas_historial_acciones' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: not possible in MySQL - you cannot update the same table in a trigger

Comment: Instead of an insert how about calling a procedure to insert and update?

Comment: "not possible in MySQL - you cannot update the same table in a trigger " well that not completly true @MadhurBhaiya you can use `SET column = <value>` to update within the same table as the trigger.. it is only not possible when using a WHERE.

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS, it's considered yelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a trigger you can change values for current record only, using `SET NEW.<column name> = value` statement. But it is not possible to update another table's records in at trigger.

In this case I'd suggest you to do follow these steps:

1. open transaction
2. update table with previous values
3. insert new record into table
4. close transaction